# Spring Kafka with Avro Deserializer

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

**I am trying to use Spring Kafka with Confluent schema registry and Kafka Avro Deserializer.
Using gradle and .avsc I have generated avro classes. Using the generated class I am sending Generic Record and Consuming the same.
I am getting below error in kafka listener:**

```html
Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = topi_name, partition = 2, offset = 149, CreateTime = 1592288763784, serialized key size = 16, serialized value size = 38, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = event_test, value = {"eventType": "test", "EventDataRequest": {"user": "54321", "panId": "1234", "empId": "5"}})

org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void className(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord>) throws com.test.kafka.exception.ConsumerException,org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException,java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.MyPojo cannot be cast to com.test.MyPojo; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.MyPojo cannot be cast to com.test.MyPojo
```

Consumer Configuration

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("consumerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("consumerFactory") ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
    return factory;
}
@Bean(name = "consumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.getConsumer().buildProperties());
    config.putIfAbsent(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}
```

Kafka Listener

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic}",groupId = "${group-id}",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void avroConsumer(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record){ 
    System.out.printf("Listener value = %s%n", (GeneratedAvroPojoClass)record.value());**//here it throws class cast exception**
  }
```

Producer Config

```
    @Bean(name = "customProducerFactory")
public ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> customProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.getProducer().buildProperties());
    config.putIfAbsent(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
}

@Bean(name = "kafkaTemplate")
@DependsOn("customProducerFactory")
public KafkaTemplate<String, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate(@Qualifier("customProducerFactory") ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> customProducerFactory){
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(customProducerFactory, true);
}
```

YML PROPERTIES

```html
custom:
  kafka:
    topic: topic_name
    bootstrap-servers:  ******
    producer:
      acks: all
      client-id: client_id
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
      properties:
        schema.registry.url: *****
        auto.register.schema: true
        value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: true
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: group_id_consumer
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
      properties:
        schema.registry.url: ******
        specific.avro.reader: true
        value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
```

Logs Consumer Config Values

```
ConsumerConfig values: 
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = ******
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
group.id = ********
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
value.deserializer = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig values: 
bearer.auth.token = [hidden]
proxy.port = -1
schema.reflection = false
auto.register.schemas = true
max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
specific.avro.reader = true
value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
schema.registry.url = [*****]
basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
proxy.host = 
schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
bearer.auth.credentials.source = STATIC_TOKEN
key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

Logs Producer Config Values

```
ProducerConfig values: 
acks = all
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [*******]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.id = client_id
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer

KafkaAvroSerializerConfig values: 
    bearer.auth.token = [hidden]
    proxy.port = -1
    schema.reflection = false
    auto.register.schemas = true
    max.schemas.per.subject = 1000
    basic.auth.credentials.source = URL
    value.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
    schema.registry.url = [*******]
    basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    proxy.host = 
    schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info = [hidden]
    bearer.auth.credentials.source = STATIC_TOKEN
    key.subject.name.strategy = class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy
```

Comment: HI I need help from you. can you tell me how this is implemented.kafkaProperties.getConsumer().buildProperties() - this is build properties using -. is it spring boot supported feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> com.test.MyPojo cannot be cast to com.test.MyPojo

That usually means there is a class loader problem - the deserializer was instantiated with a different class loader than the `@KafkaListener` method.

You need to figure out why; it's impossible for someone to answer with only static information.

**Edit:**

Make sure that you have specific.avro.reader = true in the consumers properties

Answer (score 9):

A few days ago I got the same class loading issue using `@KafkaListener` annotations consuming Avro messages in a Spring Kafka application.

It was not easy found the root cause for my application, because I found this issue only when the application was lauched in debug-mode from my IDE, otherwise run successfully.

After some debugging in some internal Spring Messaging framework handlers I found that my Avro classes were loaded in a module called "*RestartClassModule*" and of course the original reference of the classes were not the same.

So I removed this dependency from my pom.xml file:

```
<!-- hot reload - press Ctrl+F9 in IntelliJ after a code change while application is running -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

And now everything is working fine!

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was also causing problems for me.

Comment: I encountered ClassCastException with spring cloud stream kafka binder too.  The error there also mentioned `RestartClassModule`, but I didn't make the correlation until seeing your answer.  Thanks a bunch!